# Call Java method from Velocity with action onClick

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, velocity

I've got a problem with a Java app and Velocity . I use Velocity to list in a webpage an array . Now comes the problem : when I click on an element from a list , I want to open another page with informations about it . The problem is that , I use :

```
<td><a href=$obj.openAnotherPage()>$obj.ObjectName</a></td>
```

and , it is compiled at runtime . So , when I run and starts the page , automatically starts the webpage that I need , but not on click as I want . 
I tried a lot , like calling methods from JavaScript but it didn't work , it always precompiles when meets $obj.openAnotherPage() , wherever I put it . I need to open the link from  onClick (I tried this too with onClick).

Comment: That would be because `Velocity` is a serverside template rendering engine, not a magic framework that will embed Java code into HTML page.

Comment: Oh , I understand .. you have any idea how I can do what I want ?

Comment: By inserting an actual URL into your link's `href`. You `$obj` should have enough data to generate the link that can be followed to open the informations page.

Comment: I need to open a page using this method : openAnotherPage() , this is how is my java app ..anyway , I don't think it's possible .. I think

Comment: URL does not necessarily need to point to an actual HTML file. It can point to resource, linking enough information that the resource can get hold of correct `$obj` and call a method on it. Simple, really.

Comment: I don't know , when calling the method I had the problems I said in first post .. Could you let me your skype please ? Would help me a lot , I really need to fix this